# Google Glass: Developing and testing using PlayGround

Tags: java, google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-playground

I am not a person with the Google glass and I am not a person registered glass explorer. It seems like we can't develop for glass at the moment. - https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/java

[image]

Is this is it or is there another way around? I have seen a post from another member, developing a prototype with the playground. He mentioned about "uploading" HTML files to the playground, so, I also need to develop a UI prototype. But I have never seen a way to upload anything to play ground rather than typing just text in text box next to the play ground window.

Once we develop with playground (if possible) can we simply plug it to glass or do we have to redesign and develop everything with Mirror API or glass GDK ?

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's correct that you can't upload something to the playground. You can use the playground to test the layout of your cards and see how they will be displayed on Glass, you can't really do much more than that if you don't have access to the Mirror API.

I would suggest you take a look at https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api/ which lets you host your own clone of the Mirror API on App Engine with almost equivalent features and a browser-based emulator, which should allow you to develop Glassware that should run on Glass with minimal to no changes necessary, once you have access to the real Mirror API.

Comment: Great! The UI I have developed in HTML and uploaded to playground can be used in this API as well right?

Comment: Awesome! Did you write that lib? Then you are the excellent help resource!

Comment: Yes the HTML will be rendered as it is in the playground and should appear on Glass. The API itself is written in python. But you can use any language to access it, same as you can use any language to access the real Mirror API.

Comment: wow nice! Can you please help me here? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052850/google-glass-performing-click-event-or-something-similar